# gwt grails Cross Domain Request

Tags: javascript, gwt, grails, cross-domain

I wonder how can I make a cross domain request from a gwt application to a grails action. I know there is a wgt-plugin for grails but the development with this plugin is so slow (because I have to compile after each changes in the gwt-code). So I try to develop the gwt part separately and get the data from the grais application via ajax request. But the gwt application is running on a different server (gwt:port 8888, garils:port 8080). If I try to request the grails action I get this error in the browser:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/MyApp/MyDomain/myAction. 
Origin http://127.0.0.1:8888 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I try to modify the response header in the grails action:

```
response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "http://127.0.0.1:8888");
```

And if I call the action from a browser in the header I can find:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://127.0.0.1:8888
```

But is do not solve the problem. What I do wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Medrod

UPDATE:

The solution is JSONP.
On the GWT-Site my code looks like this:

```
private void jsonp() {

JsonpRequestBuilder jsonp = new JsonpRequestBuilder();
String URL = "http://localhost:8080/MyApp/myDomain/myAction";

jsonp.requestObject(URL, new AsyncCallback<JavaScriptObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(JavaScriptObject result) {

    }
});

}
```

And the grails code look like this:

```
def myAction = {
    def results = MyDomain.findAll()
    render "${params.callback}(${results as JSON})"
}
```

Thanks to Mic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web browsers have a built in security mechanism called [Same Origin Policy (SOP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) that prevent you to do that.

You can use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP), which is embedding you response in a Javascript function that will be called when the file is loaded and injected in your page as a `SCRIPT` tag.

For instance a response could be something like:

```
myCallbackFunction('a string parameter', {or:{a:json:'data'}}, ...)
```

And in your page you have a function:

```
myCallbackFunction(str, json, ...){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue simply assign a variable to your json string into the eval

```
private final native MyJson evalJson(String json) /*-{
  eval('var res = ' + json);
  return res;
}-*/;
```

For more information, see "[XMLHttpRequest cannot load. Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](http://dmottab.blogspot.com/2013/01/gwt-xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-origin.html)".